# Why 2FA on Github fails to authenticate on a new laptop

Tags: github

I have set up a 2FA authentication on my Github and I'm using the Authenticator of Google. On my old laptop, I can without a problem enter my account with 2FA. On my new laptop is failing with the same code.
I tried to use the same code in parallel and I saw in my old entering without failing, on new one otherwise failing. I'm trying to resolve this as I need to use my new laptop with Github.
I asked support from GitHub but I do not receive any right solution.
I also synched as suggested the clock but no results also.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't reuse the same code. Try a different code on your new laptop.

Comment: Also don't add irrelevant tags to questions.

Comment: @Sergio, thanks for your comment. However, I tried also now with only my new laptop and new code and it is failing.

Comment: Define "failing". Is there a useful error message?

Comment: @Sergio, when I write in Github login my Authenticator number I have this error after pushing the button:
Two-factor authentication failed.
There are no more error messages and I tried several different codes the Authenticator showed but always failing. On my old machine, I tried and I can log without a problem just writing the number I have on my phone.

Comment: yes, sounds somehow broken. I'm out of ideas. :/

Comment: Hey @Jakub, did you solve this issue, as I have the same situation and can't login using my new laptop.

Comment: hey, @asmaa unfortunately this is a very old question and now I never had the same issue. I had that issue only once and I don't remember what was done to fix it sorry :(